# Honda City 2009 : It would not start Start

Tags: engine, honda, battery, starting, ignition

My honda city 2009 AT would not start. The gauges would light up. The power windows,radio and AC worked. I was able to turn the key but when I try to start it, it will just give a sound like it is starting but it will not really start. I als tried to start it while on Park and Neutral mode but it still would not start. Please help me.

Comment: You are saying the engine will crank over, but will not fire (come to life)?

Answer (score 1):

if the engine cranks at the first time and then it stopped (like not enough of power), then you're run outta battery. but if the engine cranks but it wouldn't start then you have a problem around your fuel injection system or your igniton system.

Comment: Welcome to the site. While this may/may not be the issue, it really doesn't answer the question of how to get it running. You just aren't really giving any information. You may want to add to your answer. As it stands, it may get down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've a 2008 honda city, same as the honda jazz with the cvt transmission and one day i was driving along and the engine just shut down, i cranked several times it wouldn't just start, i did everything possible, added more petrol, changed spark plugs changed the crank shaft sensor thinking it has failed becos I noticed the plugs were not getting any spark, i just d crank shaft positioning sensor and camshaft sensor 2 times unfortunately the engine still didn't start, the fuel pump was working fine and it supplied fuel. But after several days of trials and electrical specialist working on the car we found out dat the wires harness had separated so the car wasn't getting any spark. The wire is directly under the battery on a 2007 honda city I believe it's d same as with that of the 2003 up to 2008 so if u are having the same problem with it car just look out for that wire harness b4 any other thing gets damaged while trying to start it. My case the auto electrician damaged my spark plug coils and starter

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution, once your battery is good simply do this. This may seem silly but it worked for me. Disconnect your car battery, go to you fuse box located under the steering wheel and use a thin flat head screw driver or pliers to remove all the relays one by one and resit them. To use the flat head screw driver, pry it at the bottom of relay and force it out. Strange enough it fix the starter problem. Be aware that the blue relay was not move. Reconnect the battery and try starting again. Honda City 2011